# Where to find this documentation, what is the second argument for?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

this is really simple but I don't know where to find documentation for Lightning specific javascript, can someone help out? I want to know what that second boolean argument to .get() is for in the context of using a javascript controller for lightning.

```
 packItem : function(component, event, helper) {
    var itm = component.get("v.item",true);
```

Comment: I think you have confused get with set:  `component.set("v.item",true);` should set the `item` attribute with a `true` value. `var item = component.get("v.item");` would get the value of the `item` attribute, so second param is handeled

Answer (score 1):

As of ow, as per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_attr_values.htm) there is no such Boolean second parameter in **Component.get()**

I think it may continue to work without failing until Salesforce enhances the functionality to use a second parameter.

I noted few posts being going around other forums too.

Comment: I didn't find any info about get method overloading on [aura documentation](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?topic=api:Component). Can you share links where ?